# Extract Infopath form data to CSV with Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, form, data

I have several infopath forms. Which contain data. I need to resume some of them in a CSV file.

I think I can do it with powershell. Loop in the directory and get all files.

But to retrieve data, do I have to look at the XML ? and format data as I wish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to read infopath xml forms using powershell and pick up the fields you are interested in and then write each form as a CSV record.

Useful resources,

To Read contents of XML,
[xml]$books = Get-Content C:\fso\Books.XML

$books.catalog.book.title

[source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/13/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-read-an-xml-document.aspx)

And the build the contents in a string.

Once you finish the XMl record then write it the CSV file,

Add-Content c:\scripts\test.csv "The IP XML  form 1"

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee156791.aspx)

You may have to do this by looping forms in document library

Comment: FYI, when you extract XML from a Infopath From, take care about how you built your form. Else informations are really hard to retrieve !

Comment: I came back with a problem. When I put my form file in $a (for example), then, I'm not able to retrieve every data/info, some stay in the from and I can't get them from my $a or even in XML. Any ideas ?

Comment: I didnt get what you mean. You need to get the contents of your IP xml form into  a temp. variable say $a, and then iterate it to pick up the data

Comment: I found a solution, a lil bit dirty, but it works. I download the XML file, then I get it (Get-Content), then I do my stuff, and finally, i delete the XML temp. file.